# ¿Por qué se sale el programa?

Tags: c, print

Estoy haciendo un programa de arreglo de estructuras con apuntadores y con el apuntador poder acceder y guardar los datos de la estructura, poder visualizar los datos, cambiarlo o eliminarlo y todo eso con funciones y con un menú, el problema es que a la hora de registrar al empleado el programa se sale cuando pongo la edad, es decir, ya no me deja escribir más y poner los datos que faltan de la estructura, ya le puse el fflush(stdin) pero aun así sigue pasando eso, ¿si me podrían ayudar? por favor. Este es mi código:

```
introducir el código aquí:
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void r_e();
void m_e();
void v_e();
void e_e();

typedef struct {
    int folio;
    char nombre[30];
    int edad;
    int f_n;
    int celular;
    float salario;
    char descanso[15];
    char turno[20];
    char contrato[30];
}empleado;

empleado empleados[10], *p_empleado = &empleados[10];

    int y,x=0,a,n=-1;
    char menu,p;

int main(){

    do{

    printf("-----MENU-----\n");
    printf(" 1.Registrar empleado\n 2.Modificar empleado\n 3.Visualizar empleado\n");
    printf(" 4.Eliminar empleado\n 5.salir\n");
    printf(" numero: ");
    scanf("%i",&y);

    switch(y){
        case 1: 
        r_e();printf("\nRegistro completo\n"); break;

        case 2: 
        m_e(); break;

        /*case 3:
        v_e(); break;

        case 4: 
        e_e(); break;

        case 5:
        return 0; break;*/
    }


    printf("Volver al menu s=si n=no: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&menu);

    }while(menu=='s');

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void r_e(){

do{

printf("\nRegistro: \n");
printf("folio: ");
scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->folio);

printf("nombre: ");
scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->nombre);

fflush(stdin);
printf("Edad: ");
scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->edad);

fflush(stdin);
printf("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->f_n);

printf("celular: ");
scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->celular);

printf("salario: ");
scanf("%f",&(p_empleado+x)->salario);

printf("Dia de descanso: ");
scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->descanso);

printf("turno: ");
scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->turno);

printf("Tipo de contrato: ");
scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->contrato);

printf("Desea hacer otro registro?: si=s no=n");
scanf("%c",&p);

x++;
}while(p=='s');

}

void m_e(){

    printf("\nfolio del empleado: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    do{

    for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
        if(a==(p_empleado+i)->folio){
            n=i;
        }
    }

    if(n==-1){
        printf("No existe");
    }

}while(n==-1);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí me deja registrar, ya no me deja escribir los demás datos.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema no radica en cómo haces la lectura de la edad, sino en la lectura de los datos de tipo `char` (nombre, descanso, turno y contrato).
Si bien no soy experto en la implementación del `scanf()`, sé que al usar `%s` estamos haciendo referencia a que ingresaremos un puntero a una cadena. Por lo tanto, para que tu programa lo reciba bien, deberás redeclarar los datos que te nombré de la forma:

```
char* nombre;
char* descanso;
char* turno;
char* contrato;
```

Si lo haces y agregas la limpieza del buffer (`fflush(stdin)`) antes de cada lectura, el programa funcionará, aunque perderás el límite máximo para esos datos.

Te adjunto el código corregido con un ejemplo de implementación:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void r_e();
void m_e();
/*void v_e();
void e_e();*/

typedef struct
{
    int folio;
    char* nombre;
    int edad;
    int f_n;
    int celular;
    float salario;
    char* descanso;
    char* turno;
    char* contrato;
}empleado;

empleado empleados[10], *p_empleado = &empleados[10];

int y,x=0,a,n=-1;
char menu,p;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        printf("-----MENU-----\n");
        printf(" 1.Registrar empleado\n 2.Modificar empleado\n 3.Visualizar empleado\n");
        printf(" 4.Eliminar empleado\n 5.salir\n");
        printf(" numero: ");
        scanf("%i",&y);

        switch(y)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                r_e();

                printf("\nRegistro completo\n");

                break;
            }

            case 2:
            {
                m_e();

                break;
            }

            /*case 3:
            {
                v_e();

                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                e_e();

                break;
            }

            case 5: return 0;*/
        }


        printf("Volver al menu? (s=si n=no): ");

        fflush(stdin);

        scanf("%c",&menu);
    }
    while(menu=='s');

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void r_e()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nRegistro:\n");
        printf("Folio: ");
        scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->folio);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Nombre: ");
        scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->nombre);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Edad: ");
        scanf("%d",&(p_empleado+x)->edad);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
        scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->f_n);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Celular: ");
        scanf("%i",&(p_empleado+x)->celular);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Salario: ");
        scanf("%f",&(p_empleado+x)->salario);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Dia de descanso: ");
        scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->descanso);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Turno: ");
        scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->turno);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Tipo de contrato: ");
        scanf("%s",&(p_empleado+x)->contrato);

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Desea hacer otro registro? (si=s, no=n):");
        scanf("%c",&p);

        x++;
    }
    while(p=='s');
}

void m_e()
{
    printf("\nFolio del empleado: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    do
    {
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
            if(a==(p_empleado+i)->folio) n = i;

        if(n==-1) printf("No existe");
    }
    while(n==-1);
}
```

Y la corroboración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias!